# Start default PDF App with phonegap

Tags: javascript, pdf, cordova

How can I start the default App for PDF editing with Phonegap? For instance I created a PDF with bytescoutPDF and saved it under xx/test.pdf. Now I the App starts Adobe Reader and opens the given File (Or Data URL).
So how do start that from withtin phongegap.

Or is there another way to open a PDF with phonegap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Andrew Trice built a plugin that does just this, it can be found [here on github](https://github.com/triceam/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/ExternalFileUtil) and he also did a [nice quick tutorial](http://www.tricedesigns.com/2012/08/15/open-with-in-ios-phonegap-apps/) for it as well.